# Prisma, how to know related forigen key in Database level?

Tags: prisma

how to find the related foreign key ID string at the Database level?

I use planet-scale

There is no problem with the connect id, and there is no problem with extracting it through select include. But how do we visually check the table fields? (which id is related to which id)

(Like, when we do "SELECT * FROM ABC; we usually can get forigenkey id too)

but in (planet-scale (vitess)) there is no way to see physically

only what I can do is "select" or "include"

more specifically how do I check without a "specific query"?? I just want to see the entire table field

Comment: Have you tried using Prisma Studio? With Prisma Studio, you can view your data, access and navigate related data from both sides of the relation. You would need to run the command `npx prisma studio`

Comment: @RaphaelEtim thanks it shows well and this is the only the way right?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Prisma Studio](https://www.prisma.io/studio)? With Prisma Studio, you can view your data, access and navigate related data from both sides of the relation. You would need to run the command `npx prisma studio`.

You can also use the PlanetScale shell to execute SQL commands to visualize the tables in the command line. See the [docs](https://planetscale.com/docs/reference/shell) for reference.